# how to save and retrieve image in ms access using vb.net

Tags: vb.net, image, ms-access

please someone help me. i cant get the image from datagridview. transfer to picturebox. i already save the image in ms access with a format of long binary data. thanks in advance.

```
Private Sub dg1_CellDoubleClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dg1.CellDoubleClick

    On Error Resume Next
    tVN.Text = dg1.Item(0, e.RowIndex).Value
    tNme.Text = dg1.Item(1, e.RowIndex).Value
    tCN.Text = dg1.Item(2, e.RowIndex).Value
    tAdd.Text = dg1.Item(3, e.RowIndex).Value
    tVT.Text = dg1.Item(4, e.RowIndex).Value
    tTI.Text = dg1.Item(5, e.RowIndex).Value
    tTO.Text = dg1.Item(6, e.RowIndex).Value
    Dim ms As New MemoryStream
    Dim img As Bitmap
    img = dg1.CurrentRow.Cells(7).Value
    img.Save(ms, ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    pb1.Image = Image.FromStream(ms)
    txtPIC.Text = dg1.Item(8, e.RowIndex).Value

End Sub
```

Comment: the text are already working. but i cant get the image. please somone help me. :(

Comment: OLE?.............

Comment: " i cant get the image from datagridview". "i already save the image in ms access". These statements appear to contradict each other. If you can't get the image, how did you manage to save it? Please describe your requirement more clearly. Also none of the code here relates to a database at all.

Comment: yes it is save in ole. i already save the image in ms access in ole. and i can display it on datagridview. but my problem is if i click datagridview, the informations are transfer to textbox. but i cant transfer the image to picturebox.